# How to send digitally signed mail with attachment using EWS API

Tags: java, email, exchangewebservices

I am trying to send digitally signed mail using EWS, I have implemented code for signing the mail. The mail gets sent successfully but the content of it is empty, following is the code, what am I doing wrong. any help is appreciated.

**

```
public static EmailMessage sign(EmailMessageContent messageContent)
            throws Exception {
        EmailMessage signedMessage = messageContent.getEmailMessage();
        
        char[] smimePw = messageContent.getPassword().toCharArray();
        
        CMSProcessableByteArray cmsProcessableByteArray = new CMSProcessableByteArray(signedMessage.getBody().toString().getBytes());
        try{            
            if(signer==null){
                signer = getSigner(messageContent, smimePw);
            }
            CMSSignedData cmsSignedData = signer.generate(cmsProcessableByteArray,"BC");
            MimeContent content = new MimeContent("UTF-8", cmsSignedData.getEncoded());
            signedMessage.setMimeContent(content);  
            signedMessage.setItemClass("IPM.Note.SMIME");
            
        }catch(Exception exp){
            LOGGER.error("In sign() method", exp);
        }
        return signedMessage;
    }
private static CMSSignedDataGenerator getSigner(EmailMessageContent messageContent,
            char[] smimePw)
            throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            CertificateException, Exception, UnrecoverableKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchProviderException,
            CertStoreException, SMIMEException {
        InputStream is = null;
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        try{
            is = getCertFile(messageContent.getCertFile());         
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keystore.load(is, smimePw);
            String keyAlias = getAlias(keystore); 
            if (keyAlias == null) {  
                System.err.println();  
                throw new Exception("Can't find an alias."); 
            }
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey(keyAlias,   smimePw); 
            if (privateKey == null) {  
                throw new Exception("No private key for alias: " + keyAlias); 
            }
            Certificate[] certificates = getCertificates(keystore, keyAlias);
            //Certificate[] 
            gen.addSigner(privateKey, (X509Certificate) certificates[0], CMSSignedGenerator.DIGEST_MD5);
            List<Certificate> certList = Arrays.asList(certificates);
            CertStore certs = CertStore.getInstance("Collection",   new CollectionCertStoreParameters(certList), "BC"); 
            gen.addCertificatesAndCRLs(certs);  
        }finally{
            if(is!=null)is.close();
        }
        return gen;
    }
```

**

Comment: I'd suggest starting with https://developermessaging.azurewebsites.net/2015/08/10/ews-how-to-send-signed-email-using-the-ews-managed-api/

Comment: hi, @GlenScales thanks for ur help, I went through the link u provided and I implement the code. The mail gets sent but the content of it is empty, I can't figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: @glenscales i found why mail content was empty,


CMSSignedData cmsSignedData = signer.generate(cmsProcessableByteArray,"BC");
   MimeContent content = new MimeContent("UTF-8", (byte[]) cmsSignedData.getSignedContent().getContent());
   signedMessage.setMimeContent(content); 
   signedMessage.setItemClass("IPM.Note.SMIME.MultipartSigned");

for only signed mail have to use ItemClass "IPM.Note.SMIME.MultipartSigned" which is what i was trying. But i have one more issue that is mail get send as attachment. if you know anything related this pls help.